# I installed FreeDOS on a new partition and I can't boot back to Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, freedos

Is there a way to get to windows throught FreeDOS or the BIOS

Would it be posible to install windows 8 and see if it will let me boot or at  least remove the freedos. I have a disk.

Comment: What are your hardware specifications?

Comment: Laptop - i5 2nd Gen, 6gb Ram, 750ish hdd 3 partitions (3gblank, 2gb FreeDOS, Rest is Windows

Comment: i accidentally saved it

Comment: What did you save, specifically?

Comment: i saved the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 is much newer than FreeDOS and uses a completely different method to boot. You need to restore the bootloader. Use your installation disc (burn one to a DVD+R/RW if necessary), then you can do it [manually](https://superuser.com/questions/336459/how-do-i-get-windows-8-boot-loader-back-and-also-list-both-xp-and-7), or just select the [*Automatic Repair*](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2843-automatic-repair-run-windows-8-a.html) option to have Windows restore it.

[image]

Comment: oh wow i tried that while you were posting it, and it worked!

Comment: Good to hear it’s solved. Do you see FreeDOS [in the boot menu](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/choose-another-operating-system-while-using-windows-8/Images/use-another-operating-system-in-windows8.gif)?

Comment: no while trying whatever I could think of I acctually removed it