# Restoring stock 8.1 boot order

Tags: windows-8, easybcd

I was using easyBCD to fix boot issues with another pc, but accidentally modified my own boot entries instead of the USB stick I was using. Dumb, I know.

How do I restore to vanilla 8.1 booting?

I've searched but most scenarios are more complex than my own. I don't need to dual boot or do anything fancy, just vanilla Windows 8.1 single boot.

I tried adding the entry in easyBCD before I had to restart but it didn't work. I probably didn't do it correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: How you fix it entirely depends on what you did exactly.

Comment: I deleted the boot entry in the BCD and recreated it incorrectly.

Comment: While posted against the Developer Build of Windows 8 the instructions by Tom are still correct http://superuser.com/questions/336459/how-do-i-get-the-windows-8-boot-loader-back-and-also-list-both-windows-xp-and-wi?rq=1